# Impute missing data by match IDs

Tags: r

The data set is:

```
   material      ID1         ID2

1   steel       0085        0081

2   plastics    0082        0087

3   NA          0087        0088
```

Since the ID1 of the third observation are same as ID2 of the second obs. I can impute the material of third obs as "plastics". I have thousands of obs, and a lot of missing with material. How can I impute the missing data with material by the method in r? Thank you very much.

Comment: it's not quite clear what are you asking. Database? Please edit your question and give us some more details

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps:

```
 indx <- is.na(dat1$material)
 indx2 <- c(FALSE,dat1$ID1[-1]==dat1$ID2[-nrow(dat1)]) 
 dat1$material[indx2 & indx] <- dat1$material[which(indx2 & indx)-1]
  dat1
 #  material  ID1  ID2
 #1    steel 0085 0081
 #2 plastics 0082 0087
 #3 plastics 0087 0088
```

#### data

```
dat1 <- structure(list(material = c("steel", "plastics", NA), ID1 = c("0085", 
"0082", "0087"), ID2 = c("0081", "0087", "0088")), .Names = c("material", 
"ID1", "ID2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
 "3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dataset)) {
    a <- dataset[i,]
    if (is.na(a$material)) {
        dataset[i,1] <- dataset$material[grep(a$ID1, dataset$ID2)[1]]
    }
}
```